# Are the articles of the website “言葉の違いが分かる読み物” written by one person or multiple people?

Tags: subjects, omission

There is a website called “言葉の違いが分かる読み物” (English translation: “Reading Material Where You Can See The Difference Between Words”).

As the website title suggests, it has articles that explain the difference between words. The articles are quite helpful. However, there is something about them that puzzles me. It is that they do not say who writes them, let alone how many people write them.

Here is an example from one of the articles to show why it baffles me.

> 「分からない」の意味と使い方について紹介します。
>
> **English translation:** I/we will introduce the meaning and usage of “分からない”.

To put this another way, is the subject of the sentence “I” or “we”?

Reference URL: https://meaning-difference.com/?p=7296

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from your previous questions, I think you already know the basics of Japanese, so I won't explain about the grammar for now. You were unable to find anything about the authors of these articles because **they intentionally hide such information** in order to avoid taking responsibility for the content. Their [Terms of Use](https://meaning-difference.com/?page_id=96) says 当社, so this site seems to be run by some profit organization, but they are not even willing to disclose the company name.

That site has tens of thousands of articles in exactly the same format on random topics, and it's obviously impossible for one person to write them. It's basically a clickbait site whose main purpose is to make money from online ads, and such sites are usually not interested in the accuracy of the articles. This type of article is usually written by low-paid, non-professional part-time workers, and recently some are written by AI. No matter how high the article may rank on Google, I strongly recommend that you do not use the site's articles for serious research.

Since Google's algorithm no longer rates this type of site, the number of such sites has decreased a little compared to a few years ago, but they are still the type of site most disliked by conscientious Internet users. For more information, please search for まとめサイト or いかがでしたかブログ.

Comment: I had not encountered the term いかがでしたかブログ before, but having seen many of these, I know exactly the kind you mean. These are sometimes called "blogspam" in English.

Comment: @naruto: Oh. I had not considered that. Well, I suppose that explains the lack of authorship, not to mention the articles being written with the exact same format. It reminded me of “Mad Libs”. In case you do not know, it is a game in which you fill in blanks in a short story with nouns, adjectives, verbs, and so on. In any case, thank you very much for alerting me to the website's untrustworthiness!

Answer (score 4):

Japanese is a language that, exceedingly frequently, underspecifies pronouns. What this means is that the sentence *doesn't explicitly specify* the information you're looking for. Instead, it's meant to be understood from the context. If it's absent from the context too, then it may be considered unimportant.

One way this might be translated into English is by passivising the sentence, which allows the subject role to be underspecified in a similar way:

> The meaning and usage of 分からない will now be introduced.

Comment: I have heard that Japanese seemingly uses the passive voice more often than English. Personally, I think it is more that English translation tends to render Japanese sentences in the passive voice, because the translator could not figure out the unspecified subject. Still, thank you very much for your answer!