# Usage of 脇付 depending on the sender and the addressee

Tags: grammar, words

According to these websites

https://bizushiki.com/wakiduke

https://origamijapan.net/origami/2018/06/05/wakizuke/

脇付 follow this classification when thinking on the sender and the addressee of a letter.

1. 差出人が男性：一般的な脇付
2. 差出人が男性：目上の人への脇付
3. 差出人が男性：両親への脇付
4. 差出人が女性：一般的な脇付
5. 差出人が男性・女性：師や目上の方への脇付
6. 差出人が男性・女性：高貴な人への脇付

Based on it, I have these questions related with the usage of 脇付.

1. **Respecting groups 1 and 4, what kind of person does 一般 refer to?** For example, 机下, which is used for doctors, is classified in group 1 "差出人が男性：一般的な脇付", while 侍史, also used for doctors, is classified in group 2 "差出人が男性：目上の人への脇付", so I don't understand very well who is exactly a 一般的な相手.
2. I see 男性 have 脇付 for 上目の人 (group 2) and for 両親 (group 3), whereas 女性 don't seem to have 脇付 for 上目の人 and for 両親. Then, **if a woman must send a letter towards 上目の人 or 両親, which 脇付 would she use?**

**For 上目の人, would a woman only be able to use the only one 脇付 introduced in group 5 "差出人が男性・女性：師や目上の方への脇付", that is, 函丈（かんじょう）?**

3. **Are all the 脇付 inside each group interchangeable?**

**For example, can all the 脇付 in group 1 "差出人が男性：一般的な脇付" be used for doctors like 机下 (classified in group 1)?**

When I look for each one of them on dictionaries in order to know their nuances (especially to which kind of person is used each one), the most common result I get is just "手紙の脇付の一", so I don't know very well their usage. **If you could please tell me individually each 脇付 of each group for what specific person (e.g. doctors, lawyers, professors, etc.) is used, it would help me a lot.**

Comment: Both sites fall into [this category](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/98863/5010), so I strongly recommend not trusting them. Not only do they not disclose sources, they don't even disclose who wrote it. And could you explain why you need this kind of information? Unless you're working in a medial field, you won't ever see any of them in reality.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for your comment. It's true that both sites fall into the category you linked, however, regarding 脇付, I couldn't find any real trustworthy website with academic rigor and more accurate information that clears out the doubts I have about them, and the rest of websites I looked in my research about 脇付 unfortunately seem to fall into that category too.

Comment: @naruto My interest in 脇付 is because I'm seriously studying Japanese etiquette when writing letters, and I would like to have a solid basis on this matter. If you could please help me with the doubts raised, I would be really thankful.